# Identifying signature in marriage record from Paris in 1901?

Tags: palaeography, marriage-records, france

I need help identifying the first name of the signature in the center of the image below.  I believe the surname is Pattison. It's from the bottom of the marriage record of my grandparents in Paris in 1901.  It does not appear to match any of the Pattison relatives that I am aware of and it is not the name of any of the witnesses listed in the record.  The other names are Marie Pattison (the bride), Mouchet (the groom), T.S. Pattison (father of the bride), Paul Haumant (witness), Henri Jules Pinard adj. (recorder). I can't make out the lower two signatures on the right either, but I am most interested in the unknown Pattison. 
[image: signatures in a Paris marriage record]

**Edited to add known family names:** She had two sisters alive at that time: Martha Jeanne Pattison and Jeanne Marie Louise Pattison.  Her Pattison aunts and uncles were: Sarah Green Johnson Pattison, Martha Pattison, Isabella English Green Pattison, and Lucinda Jane Pattison. Her grandmother was Isabella Johnson Green (Pattison).  Her Pattison grandfather and great grandparents were dead by then. I don't know the names of her Pattison great uncles and great aunts.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE! I think the surname is Pattison too.  The first name looks to me like "Jily" or "July" or maybe "Hy" as an abbreviation for Henry.

Comment: Pretty sure it's Hy (Henry) Pattison, as @PolyGeo says.

Comment: @ColeValleyGirl I've often seen Henry abbreviated that way but not by anyone signing their name - have you?

Comment: Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_%22Hy%22_Mayer#/media/File:Awakening_by_Hy_Mayer.jpg and http://www.immigrantships.net/v7/1800v7/henryandlouise18680515.html and http://www.lan-opc.org.uk/Sabden/stnicholas/marriages_1849-1900.html suggest signatures of Hy as well @polygeo

Answer (score 1):

It is one or two initials, not a name. I think it is most likely an H, but there is a break in the middle which suggests it is two initials - maybe T_ or I_ or J_. In those cases the second initial could be possibly S or C.

I have split the surname from the initials, which is where some of the confusion in the previous answers was coming from (the stroke below the line is part of the P on Pattison).[image: Split name]

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick google search and believe [this site](http://genealogy.mouchet.org/getperson.php?personID=I8&tree=tree1) mentions some of your relatives. Here it says, ***"...my pretty little mother married my good-looking father. One of her sisters decided to marry a lawyer and both were married the same day at a double wedding ceremony."*** Perhaps the unknown names are the 2nd couple who were married that same day in the double wedding ceremony?

I will keep doing some research to see if I can find some names that match your signatures and update this answer shortly... Could it be **LUCY** Pattison? That would be the bride's elderly aunt.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it!  Perhaps it could be Lucy.  The page you quote from is actually from my own web site. The words were written by Marie Pattison, whose marriage to Leon Felix Mouchet is the one recorded in the document with the signatures.  Unfortunately the comment was about her mother's marriage rather than her own.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my early thought that it might by Hy Pattison and the bolstering comment by @ColeValleyGirl I am going to suggest that it is the signature of a Henry Pattison.

Comment: OK. I'll have to do more research to see if I can find a Henry Pattison in the family!